# Simple multi-stage, multi-team process

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I'm new to SharePoint and am having a bit of a problem figuring out how to build a simple multi-stage process.  For example

1. Team 1

   - Fills our a form.
   - Submits the item to Team 2.
2. Team 2 receives info from Team 1.

   - Adds a bunch of documents and new
     information to the item (hopefully also based on forms).
   - Submits item to Team 3.
3. Team 3 receives info from Team 1.

   - Adds a bunch of documents and new
     information to the item (hopefully also based on forms).
   - Submits item back to Team 2.
4. Team 2 marks item resolved.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.  Currently I have a SharePoint list, based on a custom Content Type and a custom PowerApps form wired up to allow **Team 1** to create items in the SharePoint list.  I've been looking through Flow but I don't see anything that would suffice for transferring work from one department to another?

How is this commonly done?  Through multiple SharePoint lists?  If so, how do you keep all of the lists updated so everyone can see the status of an item?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. Use one library or more to store the documents instead of using attachments to items.
2. You can use look up columns to create connection between list items and documents.
3. You can use Issue Tracking list to trace the progress of an issue/task. It allows you to assign the issue to different users.

References:

[Create list relationships by using unique and lookup columns.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632)

[Working With Issue  Tracking List In SharePoint.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-issue-tracking-list-in-sharepoint/)